# Rails - regex: Get content between parenthesis(and without them) from string and get content after space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

So I'm currently stuck with regex to get values properly. Let say we have an string like `[VA03] SOME_ERROR_CODE`

What I wish to get `VA03` and `SOME_ERROR_CODE` in separate way using regex.

Currently I managed to get `[VA03]` (with parenthesis) via: `[/\[.*?\]/]` regex.

So my questions would be:

- How to get `VA03` without array parentheses?
- How to get second pard of string which comes after space, e.g: `SOME_ERROR_CODE`

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts(keep it up). Could you please give more suitable sample of `SOME_ERROR_CODE` can it be digit?  OR will it be string? Because what personally I understand is, error codes are digits only eg: 500, 401 etc. So if you could more samples of same, it will make your post more clear, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hey! Thank you! It could be string the eg: `[VA03] BlockedAcc:Account And some text can go right here.` So i kinda need to get all what is after `]` symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want either the part between the square brackets, or non whitespace chars without square brackets:

```
\[\K[^]\[]*(?=])|[^]\[\s]+
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^]\[]*` Optionally match any char except `[` `]`
- `(?=])` Assert `]` directly to the right
- `|` Or
- `[^]\[\s]+` Match 1+ chars other than `[` `]` or a whitespace char

[Rubular regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/DfY1WrQ27rjFGB)

If both values are in order, then you can use 2 capture groups:

```
\[([^]\[]*)]\s+(\S+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `([^]\[]*)` Capture group 1, match any char except `[` `]`
- `]` Match `]`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Rubular regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/V0LsmmhyGWVmvh)